# Can I count the precedence relation if all the paths on the same set of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

The path is representing for users' browse history.

I'm considering which design structure should I take.

For example,

the **red path** means the user has browsed

**[page A]->**  **[page B]->**  **[page B]->**  **[page C]->**   **[page B]->**   **[page A]**

the **blue path** means the user has browsed

**[page C]->** **[page D]->** **[page A]**

If I want to select whose browse path is **page C** earlier than **page A** ,

The answer should be **blue path**

How could I design the query in **cypher query** ,

Which design is suitable for my case?

Thank you.

## design 1 (each path share the same nodes)

[image]

## design 2 (each path should has its own nodes.)

[image]

## UPDATE

I tried to apply your query in my model,

I want to know if the **node 5231** is before than **node 7222**

But it couldn't get any output.

```
MATCH p=(x)-[*0..]->(y {code: '5231'})
WHERE NOT ()-->(x)
RETURN p
ORDER BY LENGTH(p)
LIMIT 1;
```

[image]

[image]

## Data

[model data download](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a0bdfa7a3a8d25d8f8d4#file-result-2-json)

Answer (score 0):

Creating disjoint subgraphs for each path is wasteful, and probably would not make it any easier to solve your use case.

Here is a query (that works with a unified graph) that finds the path (or one of them, if there is a tie) in which `C` appears the earliest.

```
MATCH p=(x)-[*0..]->(y {id: 'C'})
WHERE NOT ()-->(x)
RETURN p
ORDER BY LENGTH(p)
LIMIT 1;
```

This particular query ends the paths it finds at the `C` node, and does not bother to included any subsequent nodes (there could be many branches, and it is not clear which branch you would want to follow).

Comment: I tried your query but I couldn't get any output T_T pls see my update

Comment: Can you put your test data in a [console](http://console.neo4j.org/) and share it?